# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Android Enthusiasts's [sixth moderator election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Andrew T.]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5278092822052864/0).

Comment: Congrats and welcome to the team!

Comment: On SO it is common to hand the broom to the new mod and point to the pile so they can start sweeping ... enjoy!

Comment: Congrats Andrew T. wish you all the best :)

Answer (score 9):

Congrats Andrew, and welcome aboard as our new Moderator. I want to thank Xavier as well for standing up in this election at our hour of need. :)

Comment: Thanks @Firelord most importantly we have a new mod, to help you ease the workload